# petición a una Api Rest con AXIOS no espera a que llegue el resultado a mi front

Tags: javascript, frontend, react-axios

Buen día a todos, Requeiro ayuda con una solicitud que estoy haciendo con AXIOS desde REACT a mi Backend la cual me debe retornar un registro en JSON pero al parecer supera el tiempo de respuesta y continua con el flujo del programa (es como si no entrara en  la parte del .then(...) por tanto me retorna **False**  las primeras dos veces que hago la solicitud por un boton a este método, pero a la tercera vez consecutiva si me trae el registro.

Llevo poco con React y JS asi que No se bien si debo poner **Async** o **await** o en que parte debo colocarlo , para que espere a que la petición Axios se complete  (ya le tenia el return true; dentro del .then(...) e igual se lo saltaba)

```
getUsuario(usr){
axios.get("http://localhost:8088/user/buscar2/"+usr)
.then(res=>{
  this.setState({
    usuario:res.data
  })
  console.log("en el then name: "+ res.data.nombreUsuario);   //prueba
})
if(this.state.usuario.nombreUsuario !=null){  //validar
  return true;}    
else{return false;}
```

}

Comment: ¿Has intentado mover ese IF a una línea justo debajo del `console.log` ?

Comment: Hola! el problema lo tienes en el asincronismo, se realiza antes el `return` de que se resuelva la promesa. Si puedes adjuntar el código completo del componente podría ofrecerte una solución mas acertada.